# Access google docs with omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-docs, omniauth, google-docs-api

I'm using Rails and omniauth in my app and everything works fine.  Users are able to authenticate within Google, and the callback is returned and handled by my app.

I'd like to be able to allow a user to list their google docs within my app.  How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

I would check out [Data on Rails](https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/gdata_on_rails) - used on combo with Omniauth-Google you should be good to go.

> you'll want to create a GData::HTTP::Request object and pass it the Authorization header generated

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the providers for omniauth.

[Omniauth-google](https://github.com/Yesware/omniauth-google) or [omniauth-google-oauth2](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2)

There is an option to use the :scope parameter in the initializer file for omniauth.
[Here](http://hoisie.com/2011/09/12/using-google-oauth-with-omniauth/) is a good tutorial to get it working.

Comment: Well.. I don't think I read your Q right... Sorry for that.. But did you find out a way?? I am in a similar situation and now trying to use the oauth token I got from omniauth to generate an access token using Oauth gem.. I'd like to know how you went about it..